# How I can get the index of a row with a class on datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to get the index of a row that has the class "selected". How can I do that? This failed.

```
var datatable = '#mytableid';
var selectedclass='selected'; 
var table = $(datatable).dataTable();
var oSettings = table.fnSettings();

var selectedNode = table.row("."+selectedclass).node();
```

For this I received: "table.row is not a function"

Additional notes: The table use pagination and the row with the class "selected" could be on every available pagination page.

At the end I want to jump to this row on the pagination page which belong to this row.

Comment: Here's a better way to ask a question like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637704/jquery-datatables-filter-row-with-specific-class Can you make a fiddle like this? https://jsfiddle.net/subs65n8/2/

Comment: If there can be multiple pages containing rows with the "selected" class, which of these pages do you want to jump to? (This maybe sounds more like a use-case for filtering.)

Comment: If your HTML table has an ID of "example" (`<table id="example"...>`), then you need to use `var table = $('#example').DataTable()`. Otherwise `table` will not be a DataTable object, and `table.row()` will not be a function - which is the error you are getting.

Comment: @andrewjames The "selected" class is everytime at most on one row.

Comment: @andrewjames this part i already known, datatable contains the #mytableid, i've update my post to make it clear

Comment: Thank you for the update - that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following notes assume you are using a recent version of DataTables. My example uses version 1.10.22.

**Fixing Errors**

To fix your "table.row is not a function" problem, you can change the following line:

```
var table = $(mydatatable).dataTable();
```

to this (note the upper-case `D`):

```
var table = $(mydatatable).DataTable();
```

The reason you need to do this is because of how you create a reference to the [DataTables API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) object. It can be done in any one of the following 3 ways:

```
1 - $( selector ).DataTable();
2 - $( selector ).dataTable().api();
3 - new $.fn.dataTable.Api( selector );
```

In your case, you were using a mix of approaches 1 and 2.

Next, you need to change this:

```
var oSettings = table.fnSettings();
```

to this (see the [`settings()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/settings()) function):

```
var oSettings = table.settings();
```

Now you should be able to print the table row to the browser console, as a test:

```
console.log( table.row( '.selected' ) );
```

**Jumping to The Required Row**

There is more than one way to do this - but here is one simple way:

First, register a new function called `jumpToData()`:

```js
  jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'page.jumpToData()', function ( data, column ) {
    var pos = this.column(column, {order:'current'}).data().indexOf( data );
    if ( pos >= 0 ) {
        var page = Math.floor( pos / this.page.info().length );
        this.page( page ).draw( false );
    }
    return this;
  } );
```

This function is documented [here](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData()).

Now, you need to identify a piece of data in your row which is unique to that row. In my example, I am using the standard DataTables example data - so I have the following row which has the `selected` class we are using:

```html
<tr class="selected">
    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
    <td>Accountant</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
    <td>63</td>
    <td>2011/07/25</td>
    <td>$170,750</td>
</tr>
```

In my case, the row is uniquely identified by the name "Garrett Winters" in the first column (column index = 0).

Therefore I can do this:

```js
var idColumn = 0;
var idValue = table.row( '.selected' ).data()[idColumn];    
table.page.jumpToData( idValue, idColumn );
```

*An important point here: in my case the data is provided as an array of values hard-coded into the HTML table, so I access the data using `data()[0]`. If the data had been provided as an array of objects, e.g. from JSON objects, then I would need to use a different syntax here - something like `data()[personName]`.*

The whole thing is as follows:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'page.jumpToData()', function ( data, column ) {
    var pos = this.column(column, {order:'current'}).data().indexOf( data );
    if ( pos >= 0 ) {
        var page = Math.floor( pos / this.page.info().length );
        this.page( page ).draw( false );
    }
    return this;
  } );

  var datatable = '#mytableid';
  var selectedclass='selected'; 
  var table = $(datatable).DataTable();
  //var oSettings  = table.settings();

  var idColumn = 0;
  var idValue = table.row( '.selected' ).data()[idColumn];    
  table.page.jumpToData( idValue, idColumn );

} );

</script>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: @anrewjames Thanks for your detailed answear, now i understand something more as before. One question: You use "idValue = table.row( '.selected' ).data()[idColumn]; " to get a value of a cell, is there a way to use the id of the row to do the jump?

Comment: Yes, you can use the ID. If you have `<tr id="row_id_123">` then you can use `table.row('#row_id_123')`. You can see all the different ways to select a row (or multiple rows) [here](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector).

Comment: ok, i trie it in this way, but it wont work!? 
var idColumn = 0;
var idValue = table.row('#myrowid");
table.page.jumpToData( idValue,idColumn);

Comment: You can't use the `<tr>` row ID in the `jumpToData()` function. You have to use an actual piece of data from that row's data values - something which uniquely IDs that row from all other rows. In my example, I use the person's name "Garrett Winters", taken from the first field in the row's data.

Comment: sure, i've add a unique id on every <tr>-tag, thats the "myrowid", but if i trie it the page wont change, maybe its caused of idColumn=0?

Comment: oh, i think i understand. is there no way to use only the id of the row. I must use something from a column? In case of same content that will caused problems?

Comment: Yes - exactly. Something from the actual data. That's just the way the `jumpToData()` function works. So, each row has to have a unique value in it _as a data item_.

Comment: great now i've understand the things. I've add the unique id in the first column, with this it works. Thanks a lot my friend and all the best for you and your loved ones.