# Adding a class by id to a datatables row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i want to add a class to a specific row (by id of the row).

I trie to do it in this way, but it failed.

```
var table = $('#mytableID').DataTable();            
var myrow = $(table.row('#my_row_id').node());
table.row(myrow).addClass('mynewclass');
```

What i do wrong?

Please note, that the datatables has pagination pages and my content-datas comes from a ajax call

Comment: just do `$('#mytableID').find('tr').addClass('mynewclass');` it will add class to all rows, if you want to add class on specific row, then use `$(this)`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra i think it wont work on datatables with pagination pages!?

Comment: it will work on listed rows only, not after you load dynamic page data.

Comment: the datas will load by a ajax call so i think i have to go over the "api"?

Comment: yes, you can add from backend.

Comment: so, here is my problem, how i can do it?

Comment: it depends on your code, after ajax call if you are use a loop then u can do it from front end also

Comment: no i think we have a misunderstanding. The datatable list will not update again after the first ajax call.

Comment: jst show your js & html code

Comment: its to complex to seperate it. I only need to know how i can find  the node from the "my_row_id" and how i can add a class to this

Comment: Checkout the [rowCalback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) method if it meets your requirement.

Comment: why not just `$('#my_row_id').addClass('mynewclass')`?

Comment: @Pete i think it only works for the actually page of pagination and not for all other pages!? Or i'm wrong?

Comment: if it's not there to start with, then you would have to also call it on page change https://datatables.net/reference/event/page

Comment: @Pete i've test it with your suggestion and only if the row is on the pagination page in actual view, it works. If the row on another page it wont work.

Comment: is the way from my post completly wrong, whats the easiest way to get the index of a row by id and add for that a new class? I think normaly its a easie think but for me its not so....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close with your example code, but here is an updated version:

```js
var table = $('#mytableID').DataTable();
table.row('#my_row_id').nodes().to$().addClass('mynewclass');
```

This is a bit tricky, because although you can use `row()` to select a single row (the ID is supposed to be unique, of course), you need to use `nodes()` (the plural form, and not `node()`) to select the node.

See also [`to$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/to$()), for reference.

This works across the entire table, regardless of pagination.

For example, if I have the following row of HTML table data:

```html
<tr id="my_row_id">
    <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>59</td>
    <td>2012/08/06</td>
    <td>$137,500</td>
</tr>
```

Then my code will insert the required class, even though the row is initially on page 3 of the results.

[image]

Comment: Hi @andrewjames,thanks a lot, now it works! Could you make me a suggestion how i can jump directly to the pagination page of the row wich has get the new class,please?

Comment: Glad it helped! Take a look at the notes in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65325513/12567365). Do they help with your follow-up question?