# How can I get default page number of searched content?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) to sort, paginate, and search through a table of user-created notes. We have a notification/pinging system tacked on where a user can flag a note for review and a recipient will receive a notification saying there's a note that needs their attention.

When a user clicks the notification, they're taken to the page with the table of notes and using some jquery, the page scrolls down to the flagged note and highlights it. This works great with one exception.

**Issue**

Because of DataTables' default sorting, if the flagged note is a little older and doesn't appear on page 1 of the paginated results, my "scroll into view" jquery doesn't work because DataTables removes the invisible rows from the HTML.

**Goal**

What I'd like to do is search for my flagged row when the page loads and automatically jump to that page in the table before running the code that jumps down the page and highlights the row. I know I can use `search()` to find specific content and `page()` to jump to a specific page but does DataTables have a way for me to determine what page my searched content is on (assuming default sorting)?

Comment: Yes, see here for determining the datatables last state. https://datatables.net/reference/api/state()

Comment: @user12031119 - Forgive my ignorance but I'm confused on how this helps me. In what way does the datatable's last state help me figure out what page number my content is on?

Comment: @user12031119 - that is a useful technique - but is not relevant to the problem in the question. It helps user A return to their own previous state (via data saved in user A's browser). It does not let user B provide a starting-point state to user A.

Comment: @TheIronCheek - based on the limited information in your question, it's difficult to be sure, but you may be able to use [this "jump to" plug-in](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData()). An example is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65312722/how-i-can-get-the-index-of-a-row-with-a-class-on-datatables/65325513#65325513). Otherwise, we would probably need a [mre] to help you further.

Comment: @andrewjames - I think this jump to plugin is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment from @andrewjames, I looked into the [jumpToData()](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData()) plugin and it was exactly what I needed. The plugin code is pretty simple:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register('page.jumpToData()', function (data, column) {
    var pos = this.column(column, { order: 'current' }).data().indexOf(data);

    if (pos >= 0) {
        var page = Math.floor(pos / this.page.info().length);
        this.page(page).draw(false);
    }

    return this;
});
```

You just call the `page.jumpToData()` function, passing in the data you're looking for and what column you want to find it in and it'll jump to that page for you automatically.

My code ended up looking like this:

```
    var table = $('#noteTable').dataTable().api();

    if (table.row('.myTarget').data()) {
        // Need to identify unique content in the note we're trying to jump to.
        // The timestamp should work for that
        var timeColumn = 1;
        var timestamp = table.row('.myTarget').data()[timeColumn];

        // Jump to the page the flagged note is on
        table.page.jumpToData(timestamp, timeColumn);

        var flaggedNote = document.getElementsByClassName('myTarget')[0];

        //scroll down the page and highlight the row to make it stand out
        flaggedNote.scrollIntoView();
        flaggedNote.classList.add('highlight');
    }
    else {
        DisplayError("Unable to locate the requested notification.");
    }
```